# Adding Request Params In Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am trying to integrate swagger UI 2.6.1 in my spring boot project .For now I get the page as shown in the image in the link .As we can see that the post request does not have an example request parameters .

My question is how should I add these example request and where are these changes to be made in my java code or some property file is to be added? 
I want to know where and what do I need to add the request params so as it gets reflected in my swagger view ?

[image]

Comment: Could you add the code of your controller, along with the code of the object that it is supposed to receive in the request body ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request params are Java 8 Optional params then swagger dosent show them in the UI.
You have to add ".genericModelSubstitutes( Optional.class )" to your Docket-Bean creation:

public Docket sampleApi() {
  return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
    .groupName("sample-api")
    .apiInfo(apiInfo())
    .select()
    .paths(regex("/api.*"))
    .build()
    .genericModelSubstitutes(Optional.class); // add this
}